# Mark M cells on a NxN board randomly with equal probability

Tags: algorithm, random, probability

An interview question:

Given a NxN board with all cells set to 0, mark M (M < NxN) cells to 1. The M cells should be chosen from all cells with equal probability.

E.g. Mark 30 cells in a 10x10 board, then the probability for a cell to be chosen is 0.3.

My idea is to iterate all cells and on each cell compute a random number in range [1-100], mark the cell to 1 if the number is less than or equal to 30.

The interviewer is not impressed by this solution. Any good idea? (You can use any language)

Comment: The solution you proposed will mark approximately 30 cells. However, the interviewer probably wanted you to mark exactly 30 cells.  You could put the numbers from 1 to 100 into an array and shuffle the array. Then use the array as your source of random numbers, and your method marks exactly 30 cells.

Comment: @candu I don't think this is a duplicate because of the 2-d mapping aspect, but the link is very useful.

Comment: @pjs The 2D structure doesn't enter into the solution at all.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I disagree.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat is correct.  The problem is *exactly* the same: choose `M` different integers at random from the range `[0, N*N)`.  Mapping these integers onto specific cells is trivial, and has nothing to do with the underlying algorithm.

Comment: Thanks DavidEisenstat for the link and pjs btilly for answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put 70 zeros (NxN - M) and 30 ones (M) into a vector.  [Shuffle the vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).  Iterate through and map each index `k` to 2-d indices via `i = k / 10` and `j = k % 10` for your example (use `N` as the divisor more generally).

**ADDENDUM**

After checking out @candu's link, I decided to give that approach a try.  Here's an implementation in Ruby:

```
require 'set'

# implementation of Floyd's uniform subset algorithm for
# values in the range [0,n).
def generateMfromN(m, n)
  s = Set.new
  ((n-m)...n).each {|j| s.add?(rand(j+1)) || s.add(j)}
  s.to_a
end

#initialize a 10x10 array of zeros
a = Array.new(10)
10.times {|i| a[i] = Array.new(10,0)}

# create an array of 10 random indices between 0 and 99,
# map each index to 2-d indices, and set the corresponing
# element to 1.
generateMfromN(10,100).each {|index| a[index/10][index%10] = 1}

# show the results
a.each {|v| puts v.to_s}
```

This produces results such as...

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and appears to require only O(M) work for Floyd's algorithm, since on each of M iterations an element always gets added to the set.

If M is bigger than N*N/2, initialize the array with 1's and randomize placement of zeros instead, as suggested by @btilly.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of "shuffle" at that point. This should be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in expected running time `O(m)`.

First let's deal with the case where we need at most half the board.  So `m <= n*n/2`.  For this case we can keep choosing random points and changing their values, throwing away and we chose before, until we have `m` of them.  The probability of throwing away the next random choice is never more than half, so the number of random choices needed is at worst `2 m = O(m)`.

In the case where we need more than half the board, it takes time `O(m)` to flip every cell to 1, and then we use the previous solution to find `n*n - m` cells to turn back to 0.

Comment: Thanks. Actually when I failed to figure out a more correct solution the interviewer gave me hint that similar to your solution.

Comment: @Lee I am not surprised.  The solution that I offered does not have guaranteed performance, but has the best possible average performance.  By contrast the one you accepted has running time `O(n)` and in the case where `m = O(n)` has significantly worse constants.  Were I the interviewer and I was given that solution, I would have pushed for a better one.

Comment: You are kidding yourself that this is better than a shuffle. In fact it is worse. With a shuffle, you only need to perform m swaps. And then you can stop. Your approach has a minimum of m samples, but possible more.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In order to perform a shuffle you need to initialize a vector of numbers to be shuffled.  Assuming that the matrix in question is a bit-vector, that data structure will be several times larger than the matrix.  If m is much smaller than n, creating it takes several times longer than this algorithm's average time to finish.

That said, shuffling just enough to produce the first m values always requires exactly m operations.  And making random-seeming choices is expensive.

Which one is actually best will depend on circumstances.